# Mongodb - Unable to query multiple documents in Realm Trigger

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using Real Scheduled Triggers to run some background job of data validation.
In the Trigger function i want to query all the documents in the collection, but that doesn't work. But when i try to findOne document i get the response.

//Does't work, returns blank

```
const collection =  context.services.get("Cluster0").db("testdocument").collection("testcollection");
return collection.find({}).then((result)=>{  console.log('data : ',JSON.stringify(result));     })
```

//Works, returns the result

```
const collection =  context.services.get("Cluster0").db("testdocument").collection("testcollection");

return collection.find({isActive:'true'}).then((result)=>{ console.log('data :',JSON.stringify(result)); })
```

Can anyone please suggest if i am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your question used the same code for both //doesn't work and //works. But I think that what worked is findOne, that is because it returns a document while find returns a cursor. You have to use .toArray() before .then() as shown in the documentation but not obvious in any way.

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.find/

Comment: Apologies my bad, updated the snippet. Sure let me try that

Comment: Are you sure this works: return collection.find({isActive:'true'}).then((result)=>{ console.log('data :',JSON.stringify(result)); })